# correct way to set tablename in named query in reactiveCrudRepository api

Tags: spring-boot

How to set tablename name in named query? I have tried as below but
this line `String query="delete from :table1 where name=:name";` is causing error to execute query.

```
@Repository
public interface DeleteRepo extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Emp,String>{

   String query="delete from :table1 where name=:name";
   @Query(query)
   Mono<Integer> delete(@Param(name) String name, @Param(table1) String table1;
}
```

Comment: what's the error? also, have you tried to use @Modifying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add nativeQuery = true also and you should have `@Transactional` and `@Modifying` for deletion.

```
 @Modifying
   @Transactional
   @Query(value = "delete from :table1 where name=:name", nativeQuery=true)
   Mono<Integer> delete(@Param(name) String name, @Param(table1) String table1);
```

Comment: thanks for replying..but it is showing nativeQuery is undefined for annotationtype Query compile time error..could u please suggest the correct way to do it..

Comment: check you have this dependency.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: @Query need import from  import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;